# j2me is it possible to make an image appear later?

Tags: canvas, java-me, midlet, j2mepolish

is it possible to make an image to appear 5 seconds later once the app has started?
i want to make the rain appear and drop once the cloud get to the center of the emulator. I'm not sure if its in the canvas or Midlet?

Comment: How are you implementing the cloud movement? Please, add your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems to use Canvas to paint the image is more better.
If you want to show the image 5s later once the app has started, it may use a Timer to control.